# Use Create-React-App with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I'm new to Material UI and ReactJS. I've been playing around with [Create-React-App (CRA)](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap). 
My question is, can I use Material UI and CRA together to build an app?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First install `material-ui`

```
npm install --save material-ui
```

or

```
yarn add material-ui
```

`src/App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'; // add
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'; // add

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <MuiThemeProvider>

      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>

        <RaisedButton label="Material UI" />

      </div>

      </MuiThemeProvider>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In summary, these are the things to be done:

- Install necessary packages.
- import `MuiThemeProvider` component in `App.js`, Enclose the app div in MuiThemeProvider component
- Now you can import and use any component in `material-ui` like I used RaisedButton here

---

Versions of material-ui before 0.19.1 required `react-tap-event-plugin`

For those versions, you had to do make this change in index.js

`src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';   // add

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

injectTapEventPlugin();  // add

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

- import `injectTapEventPlugin` from `react-tap-event-plugin`  in `index.js` and initialise it. `injectTapEventPlugin` is used inorder
  to remove tap delay in iOS.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way that all components can be used without importing them one-by-one?

Comment: That's a fairly frequent question from people getting started. Fundamentally, JS's module paradigm is rooted in segregated, reusable components. They aren't part of a larger ecosystem that can be imported all at once. It's a fairly large topic to get into here, but, in short, no you can't import all of Material-UI in one statement.

Comment: The reason for `react-tap-event-plugin` is just as a workaround for an iOS browser issue and not essential to the problem, right?

Comment: According to the official NPM page, `react-tap-event-plugin` isn't required if you're using version 0.19.0 or higher. https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui#react-tap-event-plugin

Comment: The current documentation (Sept. 2019) shows to install using:
npm install --save @material-ui/core .
Using the above was giving me errors when trying the material ui examples